# how many Accounts i can create & how much max data that each Account can store in Anchor PDA program?

Tags: solana-program, pda, anchor-lang, anchor-accounts, data-storage

I would like to know how many accounts I can create and how much max data each account can take in Anchor PDA Program.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum size of any account is 10 megabytes. Each account address on your Solana program will take 32 bytes for the address. You can make as many as your solana program can handle. You can study more form [Solana cookbook docs](https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/pdas.html#facts), and about solana account under the "Creating" heading section in [Solana official docs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#:%7E:text=The%20current%20maximum%20size%20of,CreateAccountWithSeed%20%2C%20Pubkey%3A%3ACreateProgramAddress%20).

Comment: In addition, if you are creating a PDA account, you're limited to 10kb for the account size.

Comment: I want to know a count that how many accounts i can create in either PDA account or normal account 
right now I testing for this i haven't got any error , i created 100 accounts with normal data storage account