How to create shard accounts to manage "unlimited" account size
Since there is a limitation inside Solana transactions (1kb), and Solana account (1Mb), I'm not able to create a huge account ^^
Someone suggests me to open a new question: Handle big vector containing ton of structs
So, my question can be stupid but how can I manage an account with createAccountWithSeed?
(In order to have an account that stores all shared accounts, and those shared accounts are storing user data)
I'm considering using a structure like this one, but I don't understand how to append shared accounts. I didn't find projects on GitHub, or examples, explaining how to handle this use case.
#[account]
pub struct Data {
    pub shard_addresses: Vec<PubKey>,
    pub indexes: Vec<UserIndex>,
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Default)]
pub struct UserIndex {
    pub id: Pubkey, // Help finding the id of the UserData inside the shard account
    pub shard_pubkey: Pubkey,
}

#[account]
pub struct ShardAccount {
    pub users: Vec<UserData>,
    pub counter: u32, // Number of elements stored in the shard account
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Default)]
pub struct UserData {
    pub id: String,
    pub name: String,
    pub information: String,
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub image: String,
}

I'm sorry if it looks stupid. I'm this kind of developers who better learn with examples :/

Something like this should do the trick:
Each account is derived using a fixed seed and an increasing offset. We initialize storage accounts with length 0 and dynamically realloc them every time we add an extra element. Then, once they get full, we call the initialize instruction to just create another new account.
This can be done a bit nicer by e.g. enforcing that the offsets are always in incremental order (just ensure the previous account exists by deriving it with offset - 1 in initialize), but this should get the main idea across.
Note that this requires each user (or whoever submits data) to pay for realloc. You can otherwise also do this by preallocing the max size for the first 10 offsets and then keeping track of when those fill up to alloc another account on demand. Also the offset is a 32bit int, so that allows you a max of 4294967295 accounts * 10 Megabyte/account = ~43 Petabyte in theory. If you don't need that much, you can also switch this offset to a u16 or u8 to save some space in your instruction data.
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("Eh7kQumFPkyfyrawVp8LM7YNtp2UZbWNLRLfLnYKKE1H");

pub static STORAGE_ACC_SEED : &'static str = "storage";

#[program]
pub mod test {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(_ctx: Context<InitializeStorageAcc>, _offset : u32) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn add_more_data(ctx: Context<AddMoreData>, _offset : u32, data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.storage_account.data.push(data);
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(_offset: u32)]
pub struct InitializeStorageAcc<'info> {
    #[account(
        init, 
        seeds = [STORAGE_ACC_SEED.to_string().as_bytes(), offset.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
        payer = user, 
        // 1 byte bump, 8 bytes for the anchor discriminator, 4 bytes for the data length.
        space = 1 + 8 + 4,
        bump
    )]
    pub storage_account: Account<'info, StorageAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(_offset: u32)]
pub struct AddMoreData<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        // 1 byte bump, 8 bytes for the anchor discriminator, 4 bytes for the data length, 
        // 8 bytes (and one more for the new one) for each data
        realloc = 1 + 8 + 4 + (storage_account.data.len() + 1)  * 8,
        realloc::payer = user,
        realloc::zero = false,
        seeds = [STORAGE_ACC_SEED.to_string().as_bytes(), _offset.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump = storage_account.bump
    )]
    pub storage_account: Account<'info, StorageAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct StorageAccount {
    pub bump: u8,
    pub data: Vec<u64>,
}


Thanks for your answer, it helps me a lot.
is "realloc" called even if I don't return Ok(())?
If yes, is there a way to don't realloc automatically?
Also, is it possible to have a dedicated payer? I don't want to let the user pay, I want to pay from the program account.

No, realloc is only called if the transaction is successful. You can have a dedicated payer by instead of sending transactions client -> blockchain you do client -> server -> blockchain and sign the transaction on the server with a keypair that belongs to you.

Thanks again Ahri :)

Oh I forget, is it possible to don't realloc automatically?

Yes, just remove the realloc constraint and change the init size in the initializestorage instruction to prealloc however much space you want.

I was more thinking about realloc only if certain conditions are met in add_more_data(ctx: Context)

This is a great question, which other people might look for as well, so would be good to have this as a separate question and not just in the comments. Do you mind opening this as a separate question? (And the answer is you can do ctx.accounts.account_to_realloc.to_account_info().realloc(100, false)  to realloc it to be 100 bytes long and not zero initialized)

(you'll also need to transfer sufficient lamports to your realloced account before hand)
